# Ubuntu: wlan0 authenticates and then drops

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

Not sure what is causing this but it appears my Wlan won't connect any longer after a recent update of ubuntu:

```
uname -a
Linux p859116 3.16.0-49-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 9 10:03:23  UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running NetworkManager. It appears to authenticate successfully and then de-authenticate (?). I see somethign there about DFS Master region being unset. And then "deauthenticating by local choice" (what ever that means). Any clues? Thanks in advance. Here is what I see in dmesg:

```
wlan0: authenticate with 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f
[  123.575097] wlan0: send auth to 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f (try 1/3)
[  123.623343] wlan0: authenticated
[  123.623517] wlan0: waiting for beacon from 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f
[  123.729736] wlan0: associate with 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f (try 1/3)
[  123.731909] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f (capab=0x11    status=0 aid=1)
[  123.735668] wlan0: associated
[  123.735686] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  123.735749] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  123.737333] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  123.737335] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  123.737336] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  123.737337] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.737338] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.737339] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  123.737340] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  123.737341] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  123.737342] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[  123.737343] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[  147.246275] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:3a:07:9e:16:3f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

iwconfig:

```
 eth0      no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off

 lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Relevant: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683407 In particular, the comment: _"the correct error is not being surfaced...wpa_supplicant returns a failure to network manager, which responds by closing the connection.  Hence the "disconnected by local choice" message that you see in dmesg"_ There are likely a number of causes and solutions to this issue. E.g., other suggested fixes (worked for some, not others) include adjusting power settings: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems rather common after an update. Generally, it is because the `REGDOMAIN` variable in `/etc/default/crda` is not set, or it is improperly set.

First, issue these two commands,

```
   sudo iw reg set US
   sudo sed -i 's/^REG.*=$/&US/' /etc/default/crda
```

then reboot and try whether now your wifi works fine. Should it not, you may try looking at the output of this shell script, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Setting REGDOMAIN to my country did not help. Ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad X230, with power management on wireless card turned off.

Comment: @January You should give me something more to work on. Can you please tell me what is the output of the shell script linked above?

Comment: OK, I got it: the default authentication method chosen by ubuntu NetworkManager for the wireless I was trying to access (eduroam btw) was incorrect. Ubuntu chose tunneled TLS + MSCHAPV2, but that did not work; two other options worked: either PEAP or tunneled TLS + PAP. However, the symptoms in dmesg were identical to those here.